# Images misaligning table lines with subcolumns by /multicol

Tags: tables, landscape

## Initial problem (solved)

There's some table. It's fine till I add some images. When so, text in subcols is no longer horizontally centered and vertical lines doesn't extend. I also would like to have text middle-centered in every cell (not left-centered) and no padding or the same padding in the cells containing images to make it look properly.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\title{}

\begin{document}

\section{Some table}

\begin{table}[h]
\center
\resizebox{26cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|c|p{4cm}}
\hline
    \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1cm}}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Col1} \\ \hline
    subcol1 & subcol2 & subcol3 & subcol4\\ 
    \end{tabular}
    & 
    \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Col2} \\ \hline
   subcol5 & subcol6 & subcol7 & subcol8\\ 
    \end{tabular} & Col3 & Figures \\ \hline

    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1cm}@{}}
   text & text & text & text 
    \end{tabular}

    &
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}@{}}
    text  &   text   &   text   & text
    \end{tabular} & text &

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sheep.jpg}

    \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Edit:

Now there's a problem with adding Col0 as in the picture below. It shares cell with Subcol1.

[image]

Code 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% added
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\title{}

\begin{document}

\section{Some table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
            {|X|>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X|X|>{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X|X
             |X|X|X|X
             |X|p{4cm}|}  % added |X| for Col0
    \hline

    \multirow{2}{*}{Col0} & % wanted to fill it with Col0 text

    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Col1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Col2} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Col3}   &   \multirow{2}{*}{Figures}                          \\

    \cline{2-9}
subcol1 & subcol2 & subcol3 & subcol4 & subcol5 & subcol6 & subcol7 & subcol8 &   \\
    \hline
  text & text & text    & text    & text    & text    &   text  &  text   & text    & text 
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, 
                             margin=0pt \tabcolsep, 
                             valign=m]              
                             {example-image-a}           \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- added package `adjustbox` for vertical centering of image and adding vertical white space above and below image
- removed sub tables, now is used only one (main) table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% added
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\title{}

\begin{document}

\section{Some table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{26cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1cm}
                | p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}
                | p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1cm}|p{4cm}|}% changed
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c}{Col1} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Col2} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Col3}   &   \multirow{2}{*}{Figures}                           \\
    \cline{1-8}
subcol1 & subcol2 & subcol3 & subcol4 & subcol5 & subcol6 & subcol7 & subcol8 & &   \\
    \hline
   text & text    & text    & text    & text    &   text  &  text   & text    & text 
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, 
                             margin=0pt \tabcolsep, % added
                             valign=m]              % added
                             {example-image-a}           \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Use of `\resizebox{...}` can make unexpected troubles. Better is determine column width as they are after resizing of table. For example with use of `\tabularx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% added
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\title{}

\begin{document}

\section{Some table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
            {|>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X|X|>{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X|X
             |X|X|X|X
             |X|p{4cm}|}% changed
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Col1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Col2} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Col3}   &   \multirow{2}{*}{Figures}                           \\
    \cline{1-8}
subcol1 & subcol2 & subcol3 & subcol4 & subcol5 & subcol6 & subcol7 & subcol8 & &   \\
    \hline
   text & text    & text    & text    & text    &   text  &  text   & text    & text 
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, 
                             margin=0pt \tabcolsep, % added
                             valign=m]              % added
                             {example-image-a}           \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

Regarding to your edit of equation: with adding new column you should adequately correct

- `\cline` (to new number of columns in table),
- `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{...}` to `\multicolumn{4}{c|}{...}`
- and take special care that number of the declared columns is equal to used in table. If they are not equal, i.e. less are used in table, than happen mismatch as you experienced.

Correct code for new table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% added
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\title{}

\begin{document}

\section{Some table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
            {|X
             |>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X|X|>{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X|X
             |X|X|X|X
             |X|p{4cm}|}  % added |X| for Col0
    \hline
Col0 & % wanted to fill it with Col0 text
    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Col1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Col2} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{Col3}   &   \multirow{2}{*}{Figures}                                 \\
    \cline{1-9} % corrected number of spaned columns
subcol1 & subcol2 & subcol3 & subcol4 & subcol5 & subcol6 & subcol7 & subcol8 
        &         &         &                                               \\ % corrected number of ampersands
    \hline
  text  & text    & text    & text    & text    & text    &   text  &  text   
        & text    & text    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                                                 margin=0pt \tabcolsep,
                                                 valign=m]
                                                 {example-image-a}           \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (2)**:
if i correctly understand your comment below, you like to obtain this:

[image]

for this are done two small changes of example in above addendum:

- first cell is now `multirow` cell
- `cline` now not consider first column

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
            {|X
             |>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X|X|>{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X|X
             |X|X|X|X
             |X|p{4cm}|}  % added |X| for Col0
    \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{Col0} & % wanted to fill it with Col0 text
    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Col1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Col2} &
    \multirow{2}{=}{Col3}   &   \multirow{2}{=}{Figures}                                 \\
    \cline{2-9} % corrected number of spanned columns
        & subcol2 & subcol3 & subcol4 & subcol5 & subcol6 & subcol7 & subcol8
        &         &         &                                               \\ % corrected number of ampersands
    \hline
  text  & text    & text    & text    & text    & text    &   text  &  text
        & text    & text    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,
                                                 margin=0pt \tabcolsep,
                                                 valign=m]
                                                 {example-image-a}           \\
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Note: in above code snippet you can with comparison with this part of code in the first addendum observe that are also changed options for `multirow`. from `\multirow{2}{*}{...}` to `\multirow{2}{=}{...}`. This changes works, if you have instaled last version o`multirow` packages. with `{=}` you tel to `multirow`, that consider column formatting determined in `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{...}`.

Comment: That's great, thx. Is there any possible way to center a text horizontally inside the cells? Like Col1 and Col2?

Comment: Also got problem when I want to insert extra column (standrad one), let's say Col0 before Col1. Added |x| before >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X and tried to put /multirow before first \multicolumn call but then /cline inserts subcol1 in the Col0.

Comment: what a problem? please, edit your question and show what you change in my MWE  (I suppose in the second one) or what is your problem. From your description I can't see anything wrong.

Comment: @Taret, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: I want to to have only Col0 in the first row and cell. Right now, there is also subcol1. I want to know how to add "normal" columns before Columns with subcols.

Comment: Dear @Taret,  (i) from your edit of question follows, that you like to have what I show in addendum, (ii) add one column is not complicated, you only need to be accurate with adding of ampersands, (iii) so far you should from given examples learn how to do this, what you required you can see in column before last :)